# How is a new TestDataPublisher extension registered in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, junit, jenkins-plugins, hudson

I am trying to extend the

`TestDataPublisher`

class in order to generate an extra UI element in the test results page of Jenkins.

For some reason, the

`getTestAction()`

function is not called when the link for test results is clicked.

Please help with this issue. Thanks!

Comment: interesting. have you inherited the classes properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and this is how I resolved it.

The **string** value returned by

`getDisplayName()`

in the `TestDataPublisher` class should be selected in the post build step of

`junit publishing`

in `Jenkins`.

Hope this helps.